# composer install recognizing updated composer.json file

Tags: php, composer-php

I am familiar with the concept that, when composer.lock file is present, `composer install` command runs the packages from this file.

So when I add (manually put a `vendor/pkg` list) to "require" in `composer.json`, and run `command install` then only those packages locked in `composer.lock` files get installed.

But this understanding of mine got conflicted, when I found `composer.lock` file being git-ignored by my senior developers.

When any update on `composer.json` file is pushed to deployment server, `command install` is being run and it seems to **"install"** the updated packages.

What got me confusing is, since there's no mention of that newly added package in the composer.lock file in the deployment server, how is it being installed?

I tried the same on my local:

1. first added `vendor/pkg` in `require` of `composer.json`.
2. tried running `command install`.

And got this warning instead:

```
warning: the lock file is not up to date with the latest changes....
nothing to install or update.
```

So my question is :

why two different behaviors are being shown?

How are the newly added packages in .json and **not in .lock** are being installed in the deployment server and not in local?

I have been researching on this for a while, and its bugging me.

Maybe I am getting it wrong. Anyone there to clear this out?

Comment: When you add a new dependency in to `composer.json`, you must run `composer update` to update the `composer.lock` file, then composer will look at your new `composer.lock` to install all the dependencies. Also you should not ignore composer.lock from git to make sure  both your development and production use the same dependencies version, it will harder for you to debug if they use different version

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1. Add vendors with `composer require vendor/pkg`
2. Add in composer.json as you did, but then run `composer update vendor/pkg` (Running composer update without the package name will update all of them)